# How to ignore child element active region when parent:active is enable?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, design-patterns

I'm programming a to-do list with react. In CSS i made li:active to cause height expanding animation, however i've already programmed the `<span>x </span>` to have onClick to delete the corresponding item. My problem is that span is a children of li, and every time i click it, it'll cause a micro animation because it resides in the same space as li. Not sure what approach can i do to fix this.

this is the list structure:

```html
<ul>
 <li>
to-do text
  <span> X </span>
 </li>
</ul>
```

full code at [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/amazing-pine-7mjbs?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

Comment: Please include a [mcve] inside the question description, not only as an off-site resource link.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `button` instead of `span` and then use this CSS trick

```
<button key={i.id + "x"} refx={i.id} onClick={deleteItem}>
            x
          </button>
```

CSS:

```
li:active:not(:focus):not(:focus-within)  {
  background-color: rgb(248, 4, 4);
  box-shadow: 0 8px 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-bottom: 15px; 
 }
```

[sample codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/prevent-parent-element-getting-active-t0l33),Hope be helphful